# React setState not updating state inside stomp.js callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stompjs

I have a page that connects to a SockJS socket over stomp. But when pass a function that is supposed to change the state to the .subscribe callback it doesn't change the page's state (the rest of the function completes normally)
Here is the code:

```
export default function HomePage() {

    ...some other states...

    const [isIncomingCall, setIsIncomingCall] = useState(false)

    function initSocket() {
        const socket = new SockJS(`${process.env.API_URL}/ws`);
        const stompClient = over(socket);
        stompClient.connect(
            {},
            () => onSocketConnected(stompClient),
            onSocketError
        )
        appContext.setSocket(stompClient)
    }

    function handleIncomingCall(data) {
        const state = JSON.parse(data.body.toLowerCase());
        setIsIncomingCall(state)
    }

    function onSocketConnected(stompClient) {
        const options = {
            accessToken: cookies['logged-in'],
        };

        stompClient.send("/app/connect", {}, JSON.stringify(options));
        stompClient.subscribe(`/user/search/complete`, handleSearchComplete)
        stompClient.subscribe(`/user/search/failed`, handleSearchError)
        stompClient.subscribe(`/user/call/incoming`, handleIncomingCall)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!appContext.socket && cookies['logged-in']) {
            initSocket()
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <AnimatePresence>
                {
                    isIncomingCall && <CallModal
                        onAccept={acceptIncomingCall}
                        onReject={rejectIncomingCall}
                    />
                }
            </AnimatePresence>
            ...other page code...
        </>
    )
}
```

The initSocket function is called on page render inside the useEffect.
I have tried wrapping the callback with a useCallback and binding it to the page and calling setIsIncomingCall inside an arrow function, but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: yes, it is inside the page component

Comment: Please post the `useEffect` which calls `initSocket`.

Comment: updated the post with the useEffect

Comment: Is `handleIncomingCall` getting called ?

Comment: It is definitely being called, i can print out the data received from the socket event in it, but ```setIsIncomingCall``` is not executed for some reason, because  ```useEffect``` depending on ```isIncomingCall``` state doesn't get triggered. Out of everything that I've found on similar issues it could be because of wrong ```this``` object inside the callback, even though i don't call ```this``` myself.

Comment: There's no reason why `handleIncomingCall` is executed but `setIsIncomingCall` is not. What is the value of `state` inside `handleIncomingCall` ? Is it a falsy value ?

Comment: The value of ```state``` is always either ```true``` or ```false```

Comment: As I've said before, the ```handleIncomingCall``` is being executed correctly, and i can see when a ```true``` value is supposed to be passed into ```setIsIncomingCall```, but it just doesn't set the state.

Comment: My guess: `setIsIncomingCall` is setting the state correctly & `isIncomingCall` is indeed updated. But it's not reflected in the render due to some problem in the `<AnimatePresence>`. Try rendering the value of `isIncomingCall` inside a `<p>` to be sure.

Comment: Sadly, it is not the ```<AnimatePresence>``` 's fault, the state is just not being set for some reason

Comment: @NiceBooks  I am facing the same issue, in the callback functions I can't set any state....the callback functions are indeed invoked but they don't allow to set the state.

Comment: @NeerajJain, try adding your state into a context if you are trying to change the state across multiple pages. This fixed the issue for me, read my answer for my understanding of the problem.

Comment: @Nikitorius Please post new question if it's still not resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was:
Callbacks were initialized on first visiting the `HomePage`, but for user to set that they can receive calls, they needed to go to the `ProfilePage` and flip the switcher. In the process of going back and forth between the pages React loses the pointer to the original `isIncomingCall` state and sets it on the previous version of the `HomePage` it seems.